# How to remove text with exceptions?

Tags: text, delphi-7, edit

How to remove some text in edit.text with exceptions?

I want to remove all text except the text that I want to keep.

ex : **"THIS IS THE TEXT"**

Then i want to remove all text except **"THIS"** and **"TEXT"**

After removing the result will be like this:

**"THIS TEXT"**

I was wondering if `StringReplace()` wouldn't be working if the text have a changeable context. Or maybe `StringReplace()` will be working in this case with another method?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You'll find users more willing/able to help if you include the piece of code you're having trouble with and what you've tried so far. Please include a [Minimal, Complete Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Another useful link: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Initialise an empty result string. Search for each word that you want to keep. When you find it append to the result. Then pick up the search where you left off and repeat until there is no input left. Don't think of this as an operation on edit controls. It's pure text processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
string s = "THIS IS THE TEXT";
string v = s.Replace("IS THE", "");
```

Hopefully, it will solve your problem

Comment: i don't think so, couse the edit.text have a changeable text,so like **"this is a pen"** then i want to keep pen exist in the text, and the other text will be deleted , i thought `StringReplace()` wouldn't be working in this case couse, `StringReplace()` must have a specified object, or maybe you have another method with `StringReplace()` Would be working in this case ?